# Calculating array of dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to convert an array of days:

```
['1','2','3','4','5']
```

to an array of dates which are today +1 day , today +2 etc

I have:

```
interval_dates = []
var intervals =  rows[index+1][0].split(',')
var now = new Date();
for (i in intervals){
  // add a day
  interval_dates.push(now.setDate(now.getDate() + intervals[i]));
}
    Logger.log(interval_dates);
```

I'm seeing

```
[1.505998326018E12, 1.522500726018E12, 1.546869126018E12, 1.552654326018E12, 1.564750326018E12], ]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your array should contain numbers, not strings.

Comment: Has you tried the `toDateString()` method? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dateRange = [];

['1','2','3','4','5'].forEach(function(dayIncrement) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(dayIncrement));
  dateRange.push(date);
});

console.log(dateRange);
```

Answer (score 1):

The intervals are string, you need to get the day of today and add the interval after converting it to a number using `+interval`, so it would be `now.getDate() + +intervals[i]`, then call `new Date()` on the result, and of course change the loop from `i in intervals` to a number range:

```js
var intervals = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var interval_dates = [];
var date;
for (var i=0; i<intervals.length; i++){
  // add a day
  date = new Date();
  interval_dates.push(new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + +intervals[i])));
}
console.log(interval_dates);
```

Comment: Your answer is totally weird and produces a wrong result

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I'm afraid the console doesn't agree with you, because it's producing a correct result.

Comment: Finally after 2 fixes your solution provides the correct result. That's great

Comment: Yeah, it's better to point out an error (and suggest a fix if you know it) than to just generalize and say it's a wrong answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayOfDays()
{
    var dayA=[1,2,3,4,5];
    var today=new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var day=24*60*60*1000;
    var days=[];
    for(var i=0;i<dayA.length;i++)
    {
      days.push(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today + (i * day)), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
    //Logger.log(days);
    var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('[' + days.join(', ') + ']');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Array of Days')
}
```