# Storing an array of dates in a google sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I'm trying to convert an array of days:

```
['1','2','3','4','5']
```

to an array of dates which are today +1 day , today +2 etc, and then store these in a sheets cell. Baed on [Calculating array of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014046/calculating-array-of-dates) , I am using

I have:

['1','2','3','4','5'].forEach(function(dayIncrement) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(dayIncrement));
      dateRange.push(date);
    });

This is working and producing :

[17-09-02 08:09:19:874 PDT] [Sun Sep 03 11:09:19 GMT-04:00 2017, Mon Sep 04 11:09:19 GMT-04:00 2017, Tue Sep 05 11:09:19 GMT-04:00 2017, Wed Sep 06 11:09:19 GMT-04:00 2017, Thu Sep 07 11:09:19 GMT-04:00 2017]

However when I try to insert the array into a cell, I get the screenshot. How can I get  list of dates from the array into a cell, and can an array be stored in a cell?

Comment: You can do JSON.stringify and store that string in a cell. As long as there's no specification about how the stored array is to be used later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will store the array of dates in PropertiesService and recover them from  PropertiesService and show you that they make a proper date with Utilities.formatDate(). Just run the code and dialog comes up that is reasonably self explanatory.

```
function arrayOfDays()
{
    var dayA=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var today=new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var day=24*60*60*1000;
    var days=[];
    for(var i=0;i<dayA.length;i++)
    {
      days.push(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today + (i * day)), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy"));

    }
    //Logger.log(days);
    var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Array of Stored Dates</h2><br /><strong>This is the days array:<br/></strong> [' + days.join(', ') + ']');
    storeDates(days);
    var d=getDates();
    var s='<br /><strong>This is the array after it has been stored in PropertiesService and recovered from PropertiesService.</strong>';
    for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
    {
      s+='<br />' + Utilities.formatString('Date[%s]=%s <strong>Makes a new Date with Utilities.formatDate(new Date(d[i]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")</strong> -> %s', i,d[i],Utilities.formatDate(new Date(d[i]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
    ui.append(s).setWidth(1200);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Array of Stored Dates')
}

function storeDates(dA)
{
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('DateArray', dA.join(','));
}

function getDates()
{
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('DateArray').split(',');
}
```